# Angularjs $interval cancel is not working and on destroy and stateChangeSuccess did not work

Tags: javascript, angularjs

in below you will see part of my code to create an interval and should cancel the interval after leave the state... but it does not.

```
var init = function () {
        $translatePartialLoader.addPart("app/bottling/palletTnT/palletTnT.grid");
        $translate.refresh();

        //$scope.disablePaging = false;
        setColumnDefs();
        updateDataGrid();
        getRefreshTimer().then(function () {
            if ($scope.RefreshTime != 0 && !intervalPromise) {                   
                    intervalPromise = $interval(function () {
                        getLaneBufferData(palletTnTService.wrapperFilter);
                    }, $scope.RefreshTime * 1000);
                 }
        });


    }


    var intervalPromise = null;

    $scope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function () {
            $interval.cancel(intervalPromise);

    });
```

init is my initial function when opening page, so the problem is that;

we open this page, and it is creating interval very well and processing properly. But when I go another page and so changing state, it is still working at the background... it is so weird. But if I reload manually I mean F5, the interval is going and not working... so I do not have any idea about this, i tried so much way but did not help.

Thanks in advance...

bytheway same result with '$destroy' method.

Answer (score 0):

The way your code reads, it seems you have the `$stateChangeSuccess` piece on the same page as your interval. By the time your state change succeeds, your $scope has already been destroyed and won't fire this event. If you change it to `$stateChangeStart`, you should see the results you want.

Comment: thanks but nothing changed, still working at the background in another state

Comment: I tried to kill all intervals but it crashed other operations so killing all do not help too...